# Is there a way to determine if the neo4j database has been shutdown?

Tags: neo4j

title says it all. I know you can call a `graphDb.shutdown()` on the database, and it says you should remove all references after that, but is there a programmatic way to determine the state of the graph database, to see if it is shutdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`GraphDatabaseService.isAvailable(long timeout)`](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#isAvailable%28long%29)

> "Use this method to check if the database is in a usable state. If the database is currently not in a usable state, you can provide a timeout to wait for it to become so. **If the database has been shutdown this immediately returns false.**"

I believe the timeout is in milliseconds.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, nice to see they finally added it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way you can get it, is by using reflection. For e.g. an EmbeddedGraphDatabase, you can get it like this:

```
final Field life = InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.class.getDeclaredField("life");
life.setAccessible(true);
System.out.println(((LifeSupport) life.get(db)).getStatus());
```

Comment: Beware that this does not work for a `HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase`, you have to get the declared field on `HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase` instead of `InternalAbstractGraphDatabase`.

Comment: This actually doesn't work well. When in an HA environment, if a master/slave switch happens, the life get's marked as `SHUTDOWN` even if the DB is in a stable state.

Answer (score -1):

when in linux server console, you can use this command: (alternatively on windows,too)

```
neo4j-community-1.9.M04/bin$ ./neo4j status
Neo4j Server is not running
```

workaround when using any higher level language with REST, you might want to simply `curl` or `wget` a specific url on which the instance usually runs. if you got no data back you know it's down.

Comment: I was hoping for a more programmatic way, as we have this database embedded.